# How do I get QtCreator to make a seperate Makefile for debug/release?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

My build system parses certain variables from the `Makefile.Release`/`Makefile.Debug` to find out where the target is, start the build, etc. For some reason, I've moved to the new QtCreator with Qt 5.3 and now there is only one Makefile instead of `Makefile.Release` and `Makefile.Debug`. How do I make it go back to making two Makefiles?

P.S. shadow build is off. system is Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out: I added `CONFIG += debug release debug_and_release` to the `.pro` file and then it started building it the way I want. (I found this out by comparing the mkspecs between the two build systems, I am comparing accross different system types: mingw and ubuntu, but I cant do a proper comparison since i've already erased the previous data).